# DVI-D will work on DVI-I on GT220?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Palit GT220 Graphics Card. I've bought a DVI-D (Dual Link) to VGA Adapter in hope I could use dual monitor feature. The problem is that there's no display on the DVI-D to VGA Monitor, yet the NVidia CP detects already two monitors.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I considered making this a comment, but getting the information and picture in one of these failed. Please tell me if you actually have an expensive, active adapter and I will delete this.</sup>

> What is the problem here?

You are trying to use DVI-**D** (which is **d**igital only) to VGA (which is **analog** only).

You can not do that unless you use an active convertor to completely translate the information. A mere cable or passive adapter will not suffice.

For more information in the difference between the DVI version, check out [Wikipedia's article on DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface). Especially the part where they show [the connector](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/DVI_Connector_Types.svg/181px-DVI_Connector_Types.svg.png), its digital parts and its optional analog parts.

[image: DVI pin out, once more]